# How to include Spring JPA in the existing Spring Hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am working on one enhancement in my application. This application is Spring Hibernate implementation.But the enhancement now I am working is Spring-JPA.
Without disturbing the existing implementation I need to include JPA
Below is my DBconfiguration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"packagename","package name" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataBaseConfiguration {

    @Value("${postgres.driver}")
    private String postgresDriver;
    @Value("${postgres.url}")
    private String postgresUrl;
    @Value("${postgres.username}")
    private String postgresUsername;
    @Value("${postgres.password}")
    private String postgresPassword;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect.property}")
    private String dialectProperty;
    @Value("${hibernate.show-sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${boolean.true}")
    private String booleanTrue;

    **\\ existing hibernate flow**
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "name")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(
                dataSource);

        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(entity.class);
        sessionBuilder.setProperty(hibernateDialect, dialectProperty);
        sessionBuilder.setProperty(postgresDriver, postgresUrl);
        sessionBuilder.setProperty(hibernateShowSql, booleanTrue);

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

        **\\ existing hibernate flow**
    @Bean(name = "name")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(postgresDriver);
        dataSource.setUrl(postgresUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(postgresUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(postgresPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    **\\ existing hibernate flow**
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "manager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = null;
        transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
    **\\included newly for JPA**
    @Bean
    public org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        jpaTransactionManager
                .setJpaDialect(new org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
        **\\included newly for JPA**
    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManger() {
        return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
    }
        \\included newly for JPA
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());

        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                "some package",
                "some package");
        Map<String, Object> jpaProperty = entityManagerFactory
                .getJpaPropertyMap();
        jpaProperty.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        va.setShowSql(Boolean.valueOf("true"));
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```

When I deployed this application i am getting below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class ------
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4285)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:980)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3609)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3387)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3259)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2964)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2730)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2591)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2555)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2471)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2436)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2146)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.exprList(HqlBaseParser.java:3994)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4278)
```

Comment: How are you creating your `DataBaseConfiguration` bean?

Comment: In my servlet configuration in Mvc config class I am returing protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() { retung databaseconfiguration.class}

Comment: I guess you have syntax error in some Query which might be OK as HQL but not as JPAQL, see e.g. http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/querying-with-hql-and-jpa-ql-hibernate/  By the way somewhere in your stacktrace might be error message stating which query is not OK. You might also try removing all queries (and/or one by one) to see if that's really the problem.

Comment: @Michal Thank you for pointed.It shows error in my named query.I annotated the named query in my entity class but help me how to check the syntax error in that query bcas I ran the query in SQL editior and pasted in above the entity class

Comment: I do not see the entity with the query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach, which could be simpler. Make JPA leading and use the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to configure everything (including what you use now for hibernate). Next use the `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` to expose the underlying `SessionFactory`.

This would save you duplicate configuration and would allow you to use a single `JpaTransactionManager` for all your transactions, however you still would be able to use a `SessionFactory` or `HibernateTemplate` if you would.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"packagename","package name" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataBaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "name")
    public FactoryBean<SessionFactory> getSessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return factory;
    }

        **\\ existing hibernate flow**
    @Bean(name = "name")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("postgres.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("postgres.url);
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("postgres.username");
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("postgres.password");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", SpringSessionContext.class.getName()); 

        entitytManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                "some package",
                "some package");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        va.setShowSql(env.getProperty("hibernate.show-sql", Boolean.class, true);
        va.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```